# Coroutines, exception handling and withTimeout. Can't wrap my head around this combination

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

fun time() = System.currentTimeMillis()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
        repeat(5) {
            try {
                println("${time()} withTimeout before")
                withTimeout(1L) {
                    try {
                        delay(200L)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        println("${time()} withTimeout exception " + e.localizedMessage)
                    }
                }
                println("${time()} withTimeout done")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("${time()} exception " + e.localizedMessage)
            }
            println("${time()} -----")
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
1586923684774 withTimeout before
1586923684788 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684789 withTimeout done
1586923684789 -----
1586923684789 withTimeout before
1586923684790 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684791 exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684791 -----
1586923684791 withTimeout before
1586923684792 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684792 exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684792 -----
1586923684792 withTimeout before
1586923684794 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684794 exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684794 -----
1586923684794 withTimeout before
1586923684795 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684795 exception Timed out waiting for 1 ms
1586923684795 -----
```

On the first loop, `withTimeout done` gets printed.

**Question 1: Why only on the first iteration?**

**Question 2: If I change the wait time in** `withTimeout` **from 1L to 10L, it does not get printed. Instead, the exception is propagated to the outer try/catch, like on the next iterations (See below). Why?**

```
1586923727317 withTimeout before
1586923727333 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727334 exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727334 -----
1586923727334 withTimeout before
1586923727347 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727347 exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727347 -----
1586923727347 withTimeout before
1586923727360 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727360 exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727360 -----
1586923727360 withTimeout before
1586923727370 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727371 exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727371 -----
1586923727371 withTimeout before
1586923727382 withTimeout exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727382 exception Timed out waiting for 10 ms
1586923727382 -----
```

**Question 3: Why, even though the exception is being caught inside a try/catch block in** `withTimeout()`**, it is being propagated to the outer try/catch block?**

I appreciate and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is looking like a bug to me. Sometimes `withTimeout` rethrows the exception even if it's caught internally, and sometimes it doesn't. The second behavior seems to be triggered even by allowing a `withTimeout` to time out in a completely separate coroutine first: https://pl.kotl.in/ze45lyz2o It also does it if you specify a dispatcher: https://pl.kotl.in/c7hlNdlTM